# Why a question about electrical/ physical possibility was closed and mark as shopping suggestion?

Tags: discussion

On superuser.com I ask a question about the electrical/ physical possibility for a specific power-supply. Now my question was closed and one user comment that is a shopping suggestion, but I don't see this as a shopping suggestion if I ask it is possible.

Can anyone explain me how to write this Question in the right way to get a answer?

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/811960/it-is-possible-to-get-a-fanless-and-slimline-atx-power-supply-with-about-300-wat) is the link to the question.

Comment: As one of the initial people who casted a close vote, I did so because your question was "Anyone know a model with more power?" which can only be answered by suggesting hardware ( i.e. a recommendation ).  The question was then turned into "can I build a power supply" which is also not on topic here.  **I won't even get into the fact, the last sentence in the current revision, makes no sense grammatically.**

Comment: I don't ask for a specific model I ask if it possible. And yes it is possible, I know today. There is a technical reason that its difficult to find it, but there a some models available. And now I have a answer that won't be outdate.

Comment: @Ramhound Not everyone here is a native speaker (which is a good thing btw), excluding them because of minor grammar issues doesn't help. Using the [edit] button/proof-reading is imho the better option if can guess what op has in mind.

Comment: @mbx who says I want to exclude them?  I just pointed out the question contains something that is grammatically incorrect and should be fixed. I would fix it, of the sentence was close to being correct, but it's actually 2 statements instead of 1.  I voted the way I did because it was a hardware shopping question, i won't vote to reopen, until it's grammatically correct

Answer (score 5):

If you were going to *build* a PSU, its kind of off topic here. I suppose it would, if you phrase it VERY carefully, and were more specific, possibly fit into EE.SE or maybe DIY.SE.

If you're *hypothetically* asking whether it would be possible, its too broad. You might be able to pull it off with various different design compromises.

If you were asking cause you want to buy one, its a purchase recommendation.

There's no right way to phrase this.

In *general* we point people at chat for hardware recs, but I can't think of anyone who would actually know this.

Comment: I was searching for some Plattform for electrical Question on stack exchange but I can't find the right platform so I decide to use superuser with the tag "computer-building" it can use as discuss platform about form-factor and power Issues I think.

Answer (score 3):

As the person who cast the final close vote (moderator hat taken off) I chose to do so as the only way to find out if it was possible was effectively to "go shopping" and find one.

Asking if it is possible is a very difficult question to answer, any answers are likely to be based in opinion rather than fact and could well be obsolete by the time the answer was even posted.  Technology moves fast and power supplies change faster than you would expect. I can't tell you how to ask this type of question because in my opinion the only people who know if it is possible are the people making the supplies, and the best place to find out is their websites (i.e. go shopping). It almost certainly could be possible, but cost a small fortune, everything is possible if you have enough money.

Before now I have literally spent days trying to find out if particular types and form factor supplies are possible and available and the only way to do it is to fire up your favourite spreadsheet application, make a list of all the specifications that you need and get out on the Internet.

This is not a question that can easily be answered in the question and answer format of this site. It cannot have a simple "this is how you do it" type of answer but instead needs a long discussion of requirements and sacrifices and technologies currently available.

No matter how you phrase it you would end up with a long list of "what about this one?" type answers.

Comment: The reason to close this question is at first the expected type of answers? I expect as answer to my question not a specific product but a Answer like: "There is no concrete product but it is possible, take a look at Company XY they produce specific PSU in slim-form-factor" Or "It is not possible yet because the termal power of that 300 Watt is so high that you need ... for cooling"

Comment: @kockiren - Asking if its possible is a broad question, it also presents a problem, the answer to that question will be outdated in days/months/years which makes it a bad answer.

Comment: Its not out of date anytime because there some fanless PSU available since years (I know today) the problem is different and this will be the same problem in 2 Month or 2 Years so the sense won't be outdate.

Comment: @kockiren I hadn't fully appreciated that you were wanting fanless options. Seeing that though I would have to say that a fanless option above 100w is not likely to exist without a rather large heatsink to dissipate the heat and that would likely blow whatever space budget you have. This is actually the requirement I was searching for when I did my research. All I can really tell you is that above around 150 watts the thermal requirements either need active cooling or a large heatsink. I will try and think if we can rephrase your question but I'm not sure we would be able to properly.

Comment: @mokubai Today I know there are some PSU's with about 300 Watt available but then I need a thermal concept outside of my PSU that is the answer I need a few days ago. You are right it is possible to understand the question as shopping suggestion but this was not my sense.

Comment: @mokubai I try to rephrase my question and hope its enough for a reopening. I think it is a important question.